# Laravel redirect old links

Tags: laravel, redirect, hyperlink

I have an issue: need to redirect many broken links to the new destination. For the moment all old links are pointing to the default 404 page, but that is not an option.

I want to create a Controller in which i will define the rules for redirection.

Unfortunately I do not know how to catch all broken links to point to my new Controller.

I have made the corrections you have suggest, but unfortunately after redirect i am getting Error 500. the $redirect_url is correct, i have checked it.

Here is the new Model function:

```
public function redirect($url) {

    $redirect_url = '';
    if(preg_match('!/bukmeikari/(.*)/(.*).html!isU', $url, $matches)) {
        $redirect_url = str_replace('/bukmeikari/', '/bg/bukmeikari/', $url);
    }
    if($redirect_url != '') {
        Redirect::to($redirect_url, 301);
    }
}
```

and in the Handler.php:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $rewrite_url = new RewriteUrl();
    $rewrite_url->redirect(request()->fullUrl());

    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which laravel you are using?

Comment: i am using Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take use of `render` method of the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class to accomplish your task.

From the docs:

> The render method is responsible for converting a given exception into
>   an HTTP response that should be sent back to the browser. By default,
>   the exception is passed to the base class which generates a response
>   for you. However, you are free to check the exception type or return
>   your own custom response

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#render-method)

Comment: Ok, but how should I catch the urls and where should I define the rules for redirection ? I have a big list with rules, so I want it to be clear.

Comment: You can create a new class and call it in `render` method. And to catch urls you can use `request()` global function.

Comment: can u help me with the next issue: i am getting error 500 for the redirect

Comment: The information provided is not enough to solve the problem. Give some detail about it.

Comment: I needed to use redirection like that: return redirect($url, 301);